# How to fix Error 404 when trying to download PDF file from the public folder

Tags: php, laravel, file, pdf, download

Have been receiving a 404 error message when trying to download a pdf file that was successfully saved.

Index

```
<tbody>
    @foreach ($allData as $key => $patient)
    <tr>
        <td>{{ $patient -> card_number }}</td>
        <td>{{ $patient -> patient_type }}</td>
        <td>{{ $patient -> patient_hmo }}</td>
        <td>{{ $patient -> patient_firstname }} {{ $patient -> patient_lastname }}</td>
        {{-- <td>{{ \Carbon\Carbon::parse($patient -> patient_dob)->diff(\Carbon\Carbon::now())->format('%y years, %m months and %d days') }}</td> --}}
        <td>{{\Carbon\Carbon::parse($patient -> patient_dob)->diff(\Carbon\Carbon::now())->format('%y')  }}</td>
        <td>{{ $patient -> patient_phone }}</td>
        <td>{{ $patient -> patient_gender }}</td>
        <td>{{ $patient -> patient_kin_name }}</td>
        <td>{{ $patient -> patient_kin_phone }}</td>
        <td><a href="/file/download/{{ $patient->file }}" target="blank">Download</a></td>
        <td>


            <a class="btn btn-primary btn-rounded btn-sm" title="View Data" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-center{{ $patient->id }}"> <i class="fa fa-eye-slash"></i></a>

            <a href="{{ route('patient.edit',$patient->id) }}" class="btn btn-info btn-rounded btn-sm" title="Edit Data" > <i class="fa fa-edit"></i></a>

            <a href="{{ route('patient.delete',$patient->id) }}"  class="btn btn-danger btn-rounded btn-sm"  id="delete" title="Delete Data" > <i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a>
        </td>

    </tr>
    @endforeach

</tbody>
```

web

```
Route::get('/file/download/{file}',[PatientController::class,'downloads']);
```

PatientController

```
public function downloads($file)
{
return response()->download('upload/pdf'.$file);
}
```

Database

[image]

Error page

[image]

Comment: it would be very helpful to see your folder structure, for example where the file is located.

Comment: return response()->download('upload/pdf/'.$file);

Comment: Here is an example of the folder structure, if am right.

"C:\xampp\htdocs\hosp_erp\breeze_hosp\public\upload\pdf\1724435540364713.pdf"

Comment: return response()->download('upload/pdf/'.$file); 

Still showing error 404 | not found

Comment: Try `response()->download(public_path('upload/pdf/'.$filename));`

Comment: If you are aware you are accessing `/file/donwload/upload/pdf/{file}` and the route is `/file/download/{file}`

Comment: use correct url `http://127.0.0.1:8000/file/download/1724435540364713.pdf` in browser

Comment: response()->download(public_path('upload/pdf/'.$file));

not working

Comment: I try  using the URL as said http://127.0.0.1:8000/file/download/1724435540364713.pdf
but still not working, throwing error 404

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
This works directly without Route or any controller.


<tbody>
    @foreach ($allData as $key => $patient)
    <tr>
        <td>{{ $patient -> card_number }}</td>
        <td>{{ $patient -> patient_type }}</td>
        <td>{{ $patient -> patient_hmo }}</td>
        <td>{{ $patient -> patient_firstname }} {{ $patient -> patient_lastname }}</td>
        <td>{{\Carbon\Carbon::parse($patient -> patient_dob)->diff(\Carbon\Carbon::now())->format('%y')  }}</td>
        <td>{{ $patient -> patient_phone }}</td>
        <td>{{ $patient -> patient_gender }}</td>
        <td>{{ $patient -> patient_kin_name }}</td>
        <td>{{ $patient -> patient_kin_phone }}</td>

        <td><a href="{{ url('/'.$patient->file) }}">Download</a></td>
        <td>


            <a class="btn btn-primary btn-rounded btn-sm" title="View Data" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-center{{ $patient->id }}"> <i class="fa fa-eye-slash"></i></a>

            <a href="{{ route('patient.edit',$patient->id) }}" class="btn btn-info btn-rounded btn-sm" title="Edit Data" > <i class="fa fa-edit"></i></a>

            <a href="{{ route('patient.delete',$patient->id) }}"  class="btn btn-danger btn-rounded btn-sm"  id="delete" title="Delete Data" > <i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a>
        </td>

    </tr>
    @endforeach

</tbody>
```